# Python - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12.449899598'

Tags: python-2.7

I have one silly problem, so asking for little help with simply excercise.

I get: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12.449899598'"

-when trying to run this code:

```
def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    from decimal import Decimal
    import math
    x = math.sqrt(sq)
    y = str(x)
    z = y.rstrip('0').rstrip('.') if '.' in y else y

    for k in z:
        if k != '.':
            a = int(z)
            return (a+1) * (a+1)
        else:
            return -1
```

Four sample test are positive, just this error makes impossible to pass the excercise..
Thanks in advance for tips.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly convert strings to integers. Instead convert to `float` first and then to `int` if necessary:

`a = int(float(z))`

It is also a good idea to use `try-except` in order to catch errors of the kind you just ran into.